# Bootstrap Navbar - move one nav item to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my bootstrap navbar, I want to justify logout button to the right.

[image]

Pen demonstrating an example of the current behaviour: https://codepen.io/agrawalo/pen/mdbKYLX

Code:

```
<nav class="mb-1 navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">

    <div class="container">
        <!-- Collapse content -->
        <div class="justify-content-end">
            <!--Links-->
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item {% if current == 'Allocate' %}active{% endif %}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Allocate Stocks</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item {% if current == 'Portfolio' %}active{% endif %}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item {% if current == 'Transactions' %}active{% endif %}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/transactions">Transactions</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link {% if current == 'Leaderboard' %}active{% endif %}" href="/leaderboard">Leaderboard</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item {% if current == 'Rules' %}active{% endif %}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/rules">Rules</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item {% if current == 'Resources' %}active{% endif %}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/resources">Resources</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item justify-content-end">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve it, you need two `.navbar-nav` elements instead of one and either place `mr-auto` class on first one or `ml-auto` on second.
You also have to apply the following CSS to their immediate wrapper:

```
display: flex;
flex: 1 0 100%;
align-items: center;
```

By default, that CSS is applied through the classes `collapse` & `navbar-collapse`, which you seem to have removed.

For a complete example of navbar correct markup, see Bootstrap docs: [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/).

Your working, [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/mdbKZzY).

Answer (score 1):

To justify content to the right you need to re-order your code like I have below

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top" aria-label="Main Menu">
    <!--Toggle button-->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation" aria-controls="main-navigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
        <!--This assumes you use font awesome for the fas fa-bars class-->
        <span class="fas fa-bars"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- Container optional -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navigation">
             <!--Nav Left-->
             <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link to the left</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-1">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link to the left</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
             <!-- Nav Right-->
            <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-right">
                <li class="nav-item mr-1">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">To the right</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
</nav>
```

**EDIT:** I copied my nav, and I realise now yours just stacks, so you do not have to include the toggle button or collapse code